# How can I just combine the groups of a pandas GroupBy?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using DataFrame.groupby() to group rows with the same key, while maintaining a previously sorted row order. I wish to combine the groups back into a complete DataFrame, so rows with a common key will follow the first such row, with groups starting with largest col value first. After much experimentation and searching split-apply-combine for a separate combine method, I arrived at the following idiom which works. That it required an open coded identity function suggested to me that I'm not using GroupBy the way it was intended. Is there a better idiom?

```
df.sort_values(col, ascending=False).groupby(key, sort=False).apply(lambda g_df: g_df)
```

I'd love to know where in the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable) I could have answered this for myself.

Comment: please show as sample of your data along with the expected output

Comment: What's wrong with `df.sort_values(['key', 'col'], ascending=False)`?

Comment: Using df.sort_values(['key', 'col'], ...) will place rows with the highest key first. I need rows with the highest col first, along with any other same-key rows.

Comment: I don't understand how that's logically possible. Either you sort by `key` first, or you sort by `col` first. You can't have both at the same time. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here. Could you give an example table of how the output should look like?

Comment: IIUC, they want to sort by groups where the key is the highest `'col'` value within the group and then within group by `'col'`. This cannot be done with a simple sort, as `sort_values` cannot accept a function. But you can create that helper column with `groupby + transform`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @ALollz.

Answer (score 1):

We can `sort` first. Because `pd.unique` preservers order it finds the `'key'` ordered by their highest value. Then by setting the index and using `.loc` we can group all of them together.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                   'key': list('abababcacb')})
```

#### Code

```
df = df.sort_values('col', ascending=False)
df = df.set_index('key').loc[df['key'].unique()].reset_index()

  key  col
0   b   10
1   b    6
2   b    4
3   b    2
4   c    9
5   c    7
6   a    8
7   a    5
8   a    3
9   a    1
```

---

Another way to do what you want is to create a helper column. You want to sort by the max `'col'` value within the group, so use `transform` to broadcast the result to a helper column that we sort on and then drop.

```
df['key1'] = df.groupby('key')['col'].transform('max')
df = df.sort_values(['key1', 'col'], ascending=False).drop(columns='key1')
```

---

If you wanted to use `groupby` you're really just using it to get the index locations. A straight-forward implementation would be to just `concat` the groups, iterating over the groupby object:

```
df = pd.concat([gp for _,gp in df.sort_values('col', ascending=False).groupby('key', sort=False)])
```

However, because you just need to re-arrange the entire DataFranme there's really no need to split it just to concat everything back. The `.groups` attribute stores the indices. Chain them together and slice the original DataFrame

```
from itertools import chain
idx = chain.from_iterable(df.sort_values('col', ascending=False)
                            .groupby('key', sort=False)
                            .groups.values())

df = df.loc[idx]
```